# Quadric equation for a physics problem

Tags: calculus

[($\omega_0^2$-$\omega^2$)-2i $\omega$ $\gamma$]$^2$=1. I don't understand how can I get to that solution '1'. Any hint will be very thankful.

Comment: I would start by converting $(\omega_{0}^{2}-\omega^{2})-2i\omega\gamma$, into a complex polar form. And if that doesn't help think about what $1$ looks like in complex polar form.

Comment: By the way you should specify if you are trying to solve for $\omega$ in terms of $\omega_{0}$ and $\gamma$. Be more specific it helps you think about the problem and others best address issues that you may have.

Comment: ($\omega_0^2$-$\omega^2$)=$\gamma^2$ I found this formula but it's still does not working for my equation.

Comment: You have three parameters and only two equations to satisfy.  There might just be one or more solutions.